# Unable to parse a type in the form data request in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, form-data

While retrieving a HTTP request to my Spring boot controller from an Android device, I am facing issues while parsing the Typed objects in form data.

I need to send a multipart request with couple of files and some data, so I decided to use a form-data for this.

Now as far as the data sent along with files is a primitive, I can parse it in my controller but if I try sending a Type (e.g. List or simply Animal.class), I get the exception stating something like:

`Mismatched parameters; can't parse to string`

Is it not possible to send complex objects in form data. How can I resolve the above issue.

Comment: multipart/form-data is not exactly a popular format. Prefer to use one entity that contains everything you need.

Comment: use @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file  in your contoller.

Comment: My controller expects a @ModelAtrribute SomeClass. SomeClass is a class which contains two multipart file and a list variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer but it is a much better solution. You should compact all of your data into a byte array with a set format. Serialization takes a long time and if you know the data you're sending you don't need to use such an unspecific algorithm which takes a long time in comparison to just doing the serialization yourself.
I don't actually know what data you're sending in the Animal class but lets say you send the species (a string variable), the age and a boolean representing whether the animal is fully-grown or not.

```
class Animal {
    /* Fields and Constructors here */

    public static byte[] toByteArray(Animal a) {
        byte[] arr = new byte[a.name.length() + 4 /*(length of array)*/ + 4 /*(the age)*/ + 1 /*(fully-grown)*/];

        arr[0] = a.name.length() >> 24 & 0xff;
        arr[1] = a.name.length() >> 16 & 0xff;
        arr[2] = a.name.length() >> 8 & 0xff;
        arr[3] = a.name.length() & 0xff;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.name.length(); i++) {
            arr[i + 4] = a.name.charAt(i);
        }

        arr[a.name.length() + 4] = a.age >> 24 & 0xff;
        arr[a.name.length() + 5] = a.age >> 16 & 0xff;
        arr[a.name.length() + 6] = a.age >> 8 & 0xff;
        arr[a.name.length() + 7] = a.age & 0xff;

        arr[a.name.length() + 8] = a.grown? 0x1 : 0x0;
    }
}
```

The same can be done for the deserialization but in reverse. I don't know if i forgot some casts but I'm sure you can figure it out :)